# UISearchBar and Firebase Database

Tags: swift, uitableview, sorting, firebase, uisearchbar

```
 struct postStruct {
let title : String!
let author : String!
let bookRefCode : String!
let imageDownloadString : String!
let status : String!
let reserved : String!
let category : String!
let dueDate : String!
}
```

'Above is where i set up the structure for the post, and below, is how i reference and retrieve the data from the firebase database.

My problem is that when you set up the searcher, i do not know how to get it to search based off of the title of the post.'

```
class DirectoryTableView: UITableViewController {

 var posts = [postStruct]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    databaseRef.child("Books").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
        snapshot in

        var snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let title = snapshotValue!["title"] as? String
        snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        let author = snapshotValue!["author"] as? String
        snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        let bookRefCode = snapshotValue!["bookRefCode"] as? String
        snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        let status = snapshotValue!["status"] as? String
        snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        let reserved = snapshotValue!["reserved"] as? String
        snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        let category = snapshotValue!["category"] as? String
        snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        let dueDate = snapshotValue!["dueDate"] as? String
        snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary


        self.posts.insert(postStruct(title: title, author: author, bookRefCode: bookRefCode, status: status, reserved: reserved, category: category, dueDate: dueDate) , at: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()


    })



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return posts.count

}




override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].title

    let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    label2.text = posts[indexPath.row].author

    let label3 = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
    label3.text = posts[indexPath.row].bookRefCode

    let label4 = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
    label4.text = posts[indexPath.row].status

    let label5 = cell?.viewWithTag(5) as! UILabel
    label5.text = posts[indexPath.row].category

    let image1 = cell?.viewWithTag(6) as! UILabel
    image1.text = posts[indexPath.row].imageDownloadString

    let label6 = cell?.viewWithTag(7) as! UILabel
    label6.text = posts[indexPath.row].reserved

    let label9 = cell?.viewWithTag(9) as! UILabel
    label9.text = posts[indexPath.row].dueDate

    return cell!

}
```

'Also, does anyone know how to sort the tableview cells (posts in this case) alphabetically?'

Answer (score 0):

You can get all data already ordered alphabetically

```
databaseRef.child("Books").queryOrdered(byChild: "title").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

    var snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let title = snapshotValue!["title"] as? String
        snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

    ....

}
```

or sort your array before reload the `tableView`

```
var sortedArray = swiftArray.sorted { $0.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.title) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
```

Sample structure

[image]

Comment: i doesn't sort if you use the first method

Comment: I edited my answer. Just change `.observe(.value,` to `.observe(.childAdded`. I tested here and it worked for me.

Comment: @kileros can we do query like if my DB any Child have letter "a" in its title word name so get it in snapShot ? like "appcoda" have "a" in it and much more title like that ?

Comment: I don't believe that is possible to do this kind of query with Firebase SDK. One approach is to filter after query your items. Something like `let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
let name = snapshotValue["name"] as! String
        if name.lowercased().characters.contains("a") {
            self.queriedArray.append(yourItem)
        }`

Answer (score 0):

for sorting data according to searchBar I had used an dictionary that having all my snapshot and I compared my searchBar text in that dict and after sorting reloaded tableView here is code that you can have a look at

```
//method to get all user Details in a dict 

func getEmail() {

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")

    databaseRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists(){
            self.postData = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]

            let dictValues = [AnyObject](self.postData.values)
            self.sarchDict = dictValues

        }
    })
}
//search bar delegate
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

if self.mySearchBar.text!.isEmpty {

// set searching false
self.isSearching = false

}else{

// set searghing true
self.isSearching = true

self.names.removeAll()
self.uidArray.removeAll()
self.imageUrl.removeAll()

for key in self.sarchDict {

let mainKey = key
 //I am making query against email in snapshot dict


let str = key["email"] as? String

    //taking value of email from my dict lowerCased to make query as case insensitive

let lowercaseString = str?.lowercased()
                   //checking do my any email have entered letter or not 
 if(lowercaseString?.hasPrefix(self.mySearchBar.text!.lowercased()))!{

//here I have a check so to remove value of current logged user 
if ((key["uID"] as! String) != (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!){

//If value is found append it in some arrays 
 self.imageUrl.append( key["profilePic"] as! String )
 self.names.append( key["name"] as! String )
 self.uidArray.append( key["uID"] as! String )

//you can check which values are being added from which key
 print(mainKey)

}  
}
}
//reload TableView here
}     
}

//TableView

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    cell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!


    if self.isSearching == true {

        let imageView = (cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView)
        imageView.setRounded()
        if imageUrl[indexPath.row] != "" {
            self.lazyImage.showWithSpinner(imageView:imageView, url:imageUrl[indexPath.row])
        }
        else{
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "anonymous")
        }


        (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel).text = self.names[indexPath.row]

    }
    else {


    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this will be helpful to some using FireStore. Here I'm just setting my reference to point to the right collection. "name" is my field I wish to search by and is greater than will be checked chronologically on my string. The further they type the more defined the search results are.

```
    static func searchForProgramStartingWith(string: String) {

    let programsRef = db.collection("programs")

    programsRef.whereField("name", isGreaterThan: string).limit(to: 10).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

        if error != nil {
           print("there was an error")
        } else {
            let shots = snapshot?.documents

            for each in shots! {
                let data = each.data()
                let name = data["name"]
                print("The name is \(name!)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```